# Tab bar controller in second screen of Navigation bar controller can't see items

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Main]

I have labeled my screens in the image so it is much better.

I'm using navigation controller on screen A to go to screen B. But screen B is in a tab bar controller as well.

(screen A and screen B are in a tab bar controller)

When I go to screen B since it's in a tab bar controller it should display bar items in bottom like in the image below.

[image: Bar items in bottom]

But they don't appear. Is it because I'm navigating from screen A to screen B using navigation controller? If so, how do I go to screen A to screen B (switching from navigation controller to tab bar controller).

Comment: I am still a bit confused about what is going on. When you say `go to screen b` - do you mean you tap on the `Tickets` tab ? Also please can you elaborate on what you mean by don't see items ? What don't you see exactly ?

Comment: can you attach an image of in simulator or device (render mode) on the first and second pages?

Comment: and also can you explain what you expect in second page?

Comment: Made some edits , in order to explain the question better i hope it helps!

Comment: I don't think you should go from screen A to screen b directly. Rather from screen A, you should go to your tab bar controller and this tab controller will automatically show screen B.

Comment: Oh , yea that makes so much more sense, How do i do @ShawnFrank ;_;

Comment: Can you add the code you have now to go from Screen A to Screen B and I think I can suggest what has to be changed

Comment: guard let nextScreen = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "activitiesScreen") as? ActivitiesViewController else {
                        print("Cannot find next screen")
                        return
                    }
                    navigationController?.pushViewController(nextScreen, animated: true)

Comment: Hey @ShawnFrank i figured it out , just pushed tab bar controller instead of the screen , thank you so much for that suggestion!

Comment: Happy to help, glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I hypothesise a few possible problems which I also encountered while using tabbar controller.

1. You might be using navigation controller to move to `Screen A` to `Screen B` (`self.navigationcontroller.pushViewController`...) instead of using tabbar controller itself. You should be using **`tabBarController?.selectedIndex`** if you want to "switch" to a different tab.
2. You might not be "reloading" the items in your screen B when you load screen B, which is not really an issue due to tabbar controller. Try to check the table/collectionview DataSource methods such as `cellForRowAt`, and make sure you `reloadData()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should go from screen A to screen b directly.

Rather from screen A, you should go to your tab bar controller and this tab controller will automatically show screen B within its UINavigationController.

So give your UITabController an identifier in your storyboard first.

Then try changing this:

```
guard let nextScreen
        = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "activitiesScreen") as? ActivitiesViewController
```

to

```
guard let nextScreen
        = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabControllerStoryboardIdentifier") as? UITabBarController
```

and push this onto your navigation stack.

Comment: Wanted to give this an upvote but i dont seem to have enough rep lol.

Comment: No worries @GodLikeGill - as long as you got it to work